# How to obtain Vista Edition programmatically?

Tags: windows-vista

How to obtain Vista Edition programmatically, that is Home Basic, Home Premium, Business or Ultimate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN gives extensive answer:

[Getting the System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
[Environment.OSVersion][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant! This is just what I need as well. Thanks aku.

edg: Environment.OSVersion contains a version string but this doesn't generally give enough information to differentiate editions (also applies to XP Home/XP Pro). Also, there's the risk that this string will be localised so matching on it woudn't necessarily work.